Density of finitely supported measures in a set of measures defined by a function
Suppose that $X$ is a Polish space.
Then it is known that the set $F(X)$ of finitely supported measures on $X$ is dense in the weak topology in the set of all Borel measures $M(X)$.
Suppose that $g:X \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable and consider now the set $S = \{\mu \in M(X) \mid g \text{ is $\mu$-integrable and } \int g d\mu \geq 0\}$.
Is it true that $S \cap F(X)$ is dense in the weak topology in $S$?
If not, are there any nice conditions on $g$ that would guarantee that $S \cap F(X)$ is dense in $S$?

What if $g(x)=-1$ for all $x \in X$?

@LeeMosher Then the set $S$ is empty and $F(X) \cap S = \emptyset$ is dense in $S$
